# How to extract an int value from a string that matches a given regex?

Tags: python

I have a database url that looks like `sqlite+pool:///C:/temp/test.db?max_connections=20&stale_timeout=300` I would like to extract the `20` value.

I would do something like:

```
url = 'sqlite+pool:///C:/temp/test.db?max_connections=20&stale_timeout=300'

# default value
max_connetions = 5
if url.count('max_connections') > 0:
   # work the magic the regex would be something like
   # ".*(max_connections=)[0-9]+&.*" then $2 to get it .. or?
   max_connections = ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this.

```py
import re

url = "sqlite+pool:///C:/temp/test.db?max_connections=20&stale_timeout=300"
match = re.search(r"max_connections=(\d+)", url)

if match:
    max_connections_value = match.group(1)
    print(max_connections_value)
else:
    print("No match found")
```

(\d+) is a capturing group that matches one or more digits (\d represents a digit and + means one or more).

Answer (score 2):

You can try [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html):

```
from urllib.parse import parse_qs, urlparse

url = "sqlite+pool:///C:/temp/test.db?max_connections=20&stale_timeout=300"

q = parse_qs(urlparse(url).query)

max_connections_value = q.get("max_connections", [None])[0]
print("max_connections:", max_connections_value)
```

Prints:

```
max_connections: 20
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I liked more the smaller dep footprint solution using re only :)